# Two people take coins, the hacky solution

Tags: algorithm, puzzle, game-theory

The puzzle is:

> There are n coins in a line, coins have different values. Two players take turns to take a coin from one of the ends of the line until there are no more coins left. The player with the larger amount of money wins. **If n is even, is there any hacky algorithm that can decide whether first player will win or lose in O(1) memory and O(n) time?**

I've solved the problem with dynamic programming, but I don't know what the *hacky algorithm* is. After searching, I found the solution from [here](https://github.com/algorhythms/LintCode/blob/master/Coins%20in%20a%20Line%20III.py):

```
def firstWillWinEven(self, values):
    """
    odd_s: sum of values at odd position
    even_s: sum of values at even position
    if odd_s == even_s, the first mover cannot win if the other player mimics the first player
    if odd_s > even_s, the first mover chooses the odd position values, and FORCE the other player choose the even
    position values. The strategy and outcome are similar when even_s > odd_s.
    """
    odd_s = 0
    even_s = 0
    for i in xrange(len(values)):
        if i%2 == 0:
            even_s += values[i]
        else:
            odd_s += values[i]

    return odd_s != even_s
```

While I can understand if `odd_s != even_s`, the first person will always win, but I just couldn't understand the `odd_s == even_s` situtation. **How to prove there's no winning strategy if `odd_s == even_s`?**

Comment: The solution is incorrect. If the values are 3,1,2,4, the sum of odd-position values equals the sum of even-position values. But the first person can win by picking 4 and then either 2 or 3.

Comment: @interjay So that means the hacky solution should be `if odd_s != even_s: return true`, otherwise fall back to normal DP?

Comment: Maybe what the author of the code wanted to say is that the first player will never lose in case if `odd_s == even_s`, that is, will pick either odd-numbered of even-numbered coins, but not both. I don't think there can be any universal winning strategy for the first player for this case.

Comment: @laike9m You can do that to improve your best-case, but the worst-case performance will remain the same. Maybe there's some more cleverness that can be used but I don't see it. What you can prove is that the second player will never win when `n` is even.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I misunderstood the solution. Here's the complete solution:

```
def firstWillWin(self, values):
    """
    :param values: a list of integers
    :return: a boolean which equals to True if the first player will win
    """
    n = len(values)
    if n%2 == 0 and self.firstWillWinEven(values):
        return True

    return self.firstWillWinNormalCase(values)
```

If `odd_s != even_s` then first person will win for sure. if `odd_s == even_s`, we don't know who will win, so fall back to `firstWillWinNormalCase`.